# Remove a substring/ string pattern of a string in Erlang

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, elixir, erlang-shell

I have an xml string like

```
 S = "<B xmns=\"som2\"> <a other='v1' more='v2'/><b some=\"v3/></B>".
```

I want to remove the end tag `</B>`

```
 S2 = "<B xmns=\"som2\"> <a other='v1' more='v2'/><b some=\"v3/>"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want to remove the specific string literal `</B>` then getting a sublist will do the trick:

```
S = "<B xmns=\"som2\"> <a other='v1' more='v2'/><b some=\"v3\"/></B>",
lists:sublist(S, 1, length(S) - 4).
%%= "<B xmns=\"som2\"> <a other='v1' more='v2'/><b some=\"v3\"/>"
```

If you need a more general approach you can use the `re:replace/3` function:

```
S1 = re:replace(S, "</B>", ""),
S2 = iolist_to_binary(S1),
binary_to_list(S2).
%%= "<B xmns=\"som2\"> <a other='v1' more='v2'/><b some=\"v3\"/>"
```

---

## Update

As mentioned in the comments, providing the option `{return, list}` is much cleaner:

```
re:replace(S, "</B>", "", [{return,list}]).
%%= "<B xmns=\"som2\"> <a other='v1' more='v2'/><b some=\"v3\"/>"
```

Comment: `re:replace(S, "</B>", "", [{return,list}])` will make `iolist_to_binary/1 . binary_to_list/1` unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string:replace/3](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#replace-3) function from string module.

string:replace/3 - replaces SearchPattern in String with Replacement. 3rd function parameter indicates whether the leading, the trailing or all encounters of SearchPattern are to be replaced.

```
S2 = string:replace(S, "</B>", "", all).
```