# Erlang Replacing substring in string

Tags: string, erlang

I want to replace occurrence substring in the string with some other text in erlang.

Example for the question : I want to replace *file_name1* with *file_name2* text.

**Input** :
/user/home/*file_name1*.txt

**Output** :
/user/home/*file_name2*.txt

Description with answer appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a substring/ string pattern of a string in Erlang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703670/remove-a-substring-string-pattern-of-a-string-in-erlang)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [re](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html) module. Example in Erlang shell below:

```
12> re:replace("erlang/merl/Makefile", "Makefile", "README.md", [{return,list}]).
"erlang/merl/README.md"
13> re:replace("erlang/merl/Makefile", "Makefile", "README.md", [{return,binary}]).
<<"erlang/merl/README.md">>
14> {ok, Mp} = re:compile("Makefile").
{ok,{re_pattern,0,0,0,
            <<69,82,67,80,87,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,81,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,
              255,255,...>>}}
15> re:replace("erlang/merl/Makefile", Mp, "README.md", [{return,list}]).
"erlang/merl/README.md"
16>
```

Also if you're matching against large data, [re2](https://github.com/tuncer/re2) may help. It's NIF library though.

Comment: Thanks @YoshihiroTanaka!! :)

Answer (score 2):

If that's your specific use case- changing the filename- you can do something like this:

```
1> filename:dirname("/user/home/file_name1.txt") ++ "/" ++ "file_name2.txt".
"/user/home/file_name2.txt"
2>
```

Comment: for joining can use function from it module instead: `filename:join(filename:dirname(FName),FName2).`

Comment: Nice- even better.

Comment: Thanks, @DerekBrown, it is really great solution for filename usecase!! :) ++1.

Answer (score 0):

Since Erlang OTP 20.0 you can use [string:replace/3](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#replace-3) function from string module.

string:replace/3 - replaces SearchPattern in String with Replacement. 3rd function     parameter indicates whether the leading, the trailing or all encounters of SearchPattern are to be replaced.

```
string:replace(Input, "/user/home/file_name1.txt", "/user/home/file_name2.txt", all).
```